# drupal front page title

Tags: drupal, frontpage

I created a menu item like this

```
 $items['welcome'] = array(
    'title' => "Welcome",
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('welcome'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

and then, set the Default front pag of the site: welcome
but when I click the home icone or typing   siteaddress/welcome, the title of the page is 
'home' not 'welcome'

in addition when change the Default front pag to another address, the welcome page title is fixed!!!!!

can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `/admin/settings/page-title` and manually enter the title directly where it says Frontpage

Comment: Thank u, but this fixes the title that apears on the browser tab. I ment the title of page content.